# How to use an array and regex as pattern in preg_replace?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

So, I have got a preg_replace function that should replace the following pattern:
Usernames with an @-character in front of them.

I have got the usernames in a multi dimensonal array called allMembers() and the regex to replace any word with a @-character and spaces around it:

```
/\B@[a-z-]+\s/
```

But how do I run the usernames contained in the array through the preg_replace function? So, just one replacement for multiple patterns.

```
$mentionPattern = "/\B@[ USERNAMES FROM ARRAY ALLMEMBERS HERE ]+\s/";                                
$mentionReplace = "<a class='userMention'>$0</a>";
preg_replace($mentionPattern, $mentionReplace, $text);
```

Example:

Users on my website: John, Harry, Peter

Whenever someone adds a message like "bla bla @John bla bla", the "@John" part should be replaced by something else. Replacement thus depends on the use of @ and an existing username (that I have inside an array).

Comment: Join them in a grouped `altern|ative|list`, don't forget to preg_quote each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to use preg_replace_callback. The advantage is that you avoid to use a pattern with an alternation that is slow (in particular if you have a lot of users):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~@(\w+)~', function ($m) use ($usernames) {
    return (in_array($usernames, $m[1])) ? '<a ...>' . $m[0] . '</a>'
                                         : $m[0];
}, $text);
```

Comment: @Jonny5: it's only an example, you can easily change the pattern if needed.